# How to xmpp web-chat multiple tabs

Tags: xmpp, openfire, strophe

i have web-chat from xmpp-server Openfire 3.8.1 and StropheJS. Connection is by XMPPHP. A Strophe attached session from cookie. If web-chat open in two tabs are window, strophe is disconnecting. How solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you. But how to define a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

For every new tab, you have to generate a unique resource for it. Then use Strophe to attach it in client and prebind.